# Is it required to call UITableView.deleteRows() when deleting data items not shown on screen？

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

In my App's `UITableView`, when user swipes to delete an item, the App deletes not only the selected item but also other related items in the data source, which may be shown or not shown on the screen at the time. My first thought was that I need to iterate all cells in the `UITableView` to get the cells for those data items and call `UITableView.deleteRows()` to delete them. But a quick search on SO showed that it's impossible to iterate all cells due to the way how `UITableView` works.

So I wonder what's the right way to synchronize `UITableView` with data source in my case? Is it OK to just iterate `UITableView.visibleCells`? But if I understand it correctly, `UITableView` prefetches (I mean it gets more items than it needs to show on the screen) for performance reason, so what if the data item I delete are among the items that are prefetched by `UITableView` but are not shown yet? Should I call `UITableView.deleteRows()` to delete them too? But how can I get those cells?

Comment: Yes, you should delete any rows where you are deleting the corresponding item from the data model. You don't need the cell to delete a row; you just need the index path, which you should be able to compute based on the data you are deleting

Comment: @Paulw11 Got it. Thanks!